# React-hot-loader: `hot` could not find the `name` of the the `module` you have provided

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, react-hooks

I'm using Webpack 4 to create a React project with hooks and I'm trying to get the changes to reload on page live using `react-hot-loader` following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ReeganExE/react-hooks-with-hot-reload-boilerplate-a80f0eca0e38).

But I when I try `npm start` I get following error on the browser:

> Error: React-hot-loader: `hot` could not find the `name` of the the
>   `module` you have provided

This is my `App.js` contents:

```
import React from 'react';
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader';
import Header from './Header';

function App() {

  return (
    <section className="main">
      <Header />
    </section>
  );
}
export default hot(App);
```

Alternately I tried importing `hot` from `react-hot-loader/root`, but this way I get a different error:

> Error: React-Hot-Loader: `react-hot-loader/root` is not supported on
>   your system. Please use `import {hot} from "react-hot-loader"` instead

How could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looking at my webpack configs:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(env.NODE_ENV) }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true,
  },
```

I had used `webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()` in plugins and `hot: true` in devServer which made the second error if I would use `react-hot-loader/root`.

So removing `new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()` from the `webpack.config.js`, solved my problem.

Comment: I tried to remove new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), from webpack config but error still persist.

Comment: @DmitryMalugin Are you importing from `'react-hot-loader/root'` or just `'react-hot-loader'`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be requiring it before react:

```
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root';
import React from 'react';
```

The package [documentation](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader) mentions this.

Answer (score 0):

import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader';
export default hot(module)(App);

or

import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root';
export default hot(App);